# How to correctly create function for formatter on PHP in Yii2 Highcharts extension

Tags: php, highcharts, yii2, tooltip

I have to display some special information when my mouse is over a concrete point in a chart that is provided by Highcharts. I am using the Highcharts extension for Yii2.

**My Code**

```
'tooltip' => [
               'enabled' => true,
               'footerFormat' => true,
               'formatter' => "js:function() {
                    return 'my special information';
                }"
             ],
```

The data that comes from controller is correct.
However there is nothing different - tooltip is still the  default

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which `Yii2 Extrenesion` you use? For example, this one has explained how to use formatter: https://github.com/miloschuman/yii2-highcharts#tips

Comment: @paweł-fus
I am using the Highcharts extension. Also i tried this code 
`code`
'tooltip' => [
   'formatter' => new JsExpression('function(){ return "my special data"; }')
],`code`
And it does nothing.
Maybe i not correctly understood you "Which Yii2 Extrenesion you use?"?

Comment: Sorry `Extension` should be. I just used google, and found at least three extensions: [2amigos](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-highcharts-widget), [maddoger](https://packagist.org/packages/maddoger/yii2-highcharts) and [khotim](https://packagist.org/packages/khotim/yii2-highcharts).

Comment: @paweł-fus sorry, my bad. All is working fine. I just duplicate 'tooltip' option. And my tooltip that i want to use was override by tooltip that i forgot to remove from my code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. My bad. All is working fine. I just duplicate 'tooltip' option. And my tooltip that i want to use was override by tooltip that i forgot to remove from my code)