# How to Modify ToolTips in Yii2 using dosamigos\chartjs\ChartJs?

Tags: php, yii2, chart.js

I want to change the tooltip of a Chart I made in Yii2 using [dosamigos\chartjs\ChartJs](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-chartjs-widget) which is based on [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/)

My problem comes when I try to modify the Tooltip part of the chart. I am unable to achieve it. I have tried using multiTooltipTemplate, tooltips.callback and tooltipTemplate properties but I have not succeeded yet.

Below are 2 pictures of my Chart, What I want to achive is this:

1. The ToolTip of the inner chart (first image) should say something like this: "A: 119 Products" or "B: 230 Products" or "C: 540 products" depending on which section of the chart you are in (red,blue,yellow).
2. The Tooltip of the outer chart (second image) should say something like "A:  $5,966,671.64" or "B:  $1,120,022.50" or "C:  $966,671.64" depending on which color you are in (red,blue,yellow).

[image]
[image]

Bellow is the code I am using to generate the chart in my view:

```
<?= ChartJs::widget([
 'type' => 'pie',
 'options' => [
     'height' => 200,
     'width' => 600,
     'responsive' => true,
     'animation'=> true,
     'barValueSpacing' => 5,
     'barDatasetSpacing' => 1,
     //'tooltipFillColor'=> "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)",
     //'multiTooltipTemplate' => "<%= Value %> - <%= value %>",
     // String - Template string for single tooltips,
     //'tooltipTemplate'=>  "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>",

     // String - Template string for single tooltips,
     //'multiTooltipTemplate'=>  "<%= value %>",

     'tooltips'=> [
      'callbacks'=> [
          'title' =>  '***** My custom label title *****'           

          ]
    ],

],
 'data' => [
       'datasets' => [
          [
              'label' => 'Valor Inventario',
              'data'=> [$valorInventarioA, $valorInventarioB, $valorInventarioC],
              'backgroundColor'=> [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
              ],
              'borderColor'=> [
                  'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
              ]
          ],
          [
                 'label' => 'Cantidad Items',
                'data'=> [$grupoACount, $grupoBCount, $grupoCCount],
             'backgroundColor'=> [
                 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
             ],
             'borderColor'=> [
                 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
             ]
          ]
      ],

       // These labels appear in the legend and in the tooltips when hovering different arcs
       'labels' => [
           'A',
           'B',
           'C'
       ]
 ]
]);?>
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Sure, I can see if that works. But I have seen how it is done in JavaScript with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38626852 So I think the problem is my translation from JavaScript to PHP

Comment: Not yet. But I am trying what is shown in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/35767575/2437857 Specifically 

 'formatter' => "js:function() {
                    return 'my special information';
                }"
This is a different chart extension, but maybe the concept can work here as well. But I have bot achieved it yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify the tooltip, you can use a [callback function](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) for tooltips label, as such :

```
...
'clientOptions' => [
    'tooltips'=> [
         'callbacks'=> [
             'label'=> new JsExpression("function(t, d) {
                     var label = d.labels[t.index];
                     var data = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].data[t.index];
                     if (t.datasetIndex === 0)
                     return label + ': ' + data + ' Products';
                     else if (t.datasetIndex === 1)
                     return label + ': $' + data.toLocaleString();
              }")
          ]
     ],
     ...
],
...
```

**note :**

- correct property name for chart options is `clientOptions`
- `JsExpression` class should be used to compile the JS callback function

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far. This is a very clever approach but even when I tried several variations of your code I could not make it work neither. I am growing tired of dosamigos\chartjs\ChartJs. So what I am doing now is to create the Chart using only JavaScript and the Chart.js without any PHP extension in the middle, it is not my favorite approach but is the only way I am achieving what i want

Thank you!

Comment: I could upvote because of your help, but I have not been able to resolve the question. I am just changing the approach!

Comment: The solution is basically same in both cases.. you just somehow need to transpile the syntax to use that in Yii2.. that's it.

Comment: Ah! Got some time to do few testing and it turned out that the previous answer *(syntax)* was actually correct. The issue was infact with the property name that you're using for chart options. I've updated the answer. Hope everything works fine for you now!!